# Can we set String column as partitionColumn?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Table only has String column as primary column `EMPLOYEE_ID` how to partition it.

`val destination = spark.read.options(options).jdbc(options("url"), options("dbtable"), "EMPLOYEE_ID", P00100001, P00100005000000, 10, new java.util.Properties()).rdd.map(_.mkString(","))`

Is there any other way to Read JDBC table and process it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Only integer columns can be used here. If your database supports some variant of rowid, which is integer or can be casted to integer, you can extract it in a query (pseudocode):

```
 (SELECT CAST(rowid AS INTEGER), * FROM TABLE) AS tmp
```

Comment: `set @row_num = 0;
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number,s.* FROM source s;` this query gives row number along with the table data, but how to execute this statement`set @row_num = 0; and SELECT max(@row_num) as row_number;` to set @rom_num = 0 and to get the  upperbound value from spark.

Comment: In that case, there will be one additional column [CAST(rowid AS INTEGER)] when we write DataFrame to any target? How to handle that ?